# Where can I find a gravatar-like script for cropping images in the client's browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a good javascript script similar to the one used by gravatar or Yahoo Profiles, I simply want the users to be able to control how their avatar will look like.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about **[jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)**?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody else is also interested in finding a javascript image cropper, I came across these pages, hope they can help you too:

http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/
http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-image-cropping-scripts/